# Rolling sum over a Seq with Date as key

Tags: scala

I'm working on a small personal project and am trying to re-write the codebase from Python to Scala so that I can be a little more competent functional programmer.

I am working with a `Seq` that contains stock data and need to create a running sum of volume traded for each day.

My code so far is:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

case class SymbolData(date: DateTime, open: Double, high: Double, low: Double, close: Double, adjClose: Double, volume: Int)

def dateTimeHelper(date: String): DateTime = {
       DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").parseDateTime(date)
}

val sampleData: Seq[SymbolData] = Seq(
       SymbolData(dateTimeHelper("2019-01-01"), 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10),
       SymbolData(dateTimeHelper("2019-01-02"), 3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 8.0, 20),
       SymbolData(dateTimeHelper("2019-01-03"), 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10),
       SymbolData(dateTimeHelper("2019-01-04"), 4.0, 3.0, 2.5, 2.3, 5.3, 7))
```

Not all dates may be present so I do not think using a sliding window will be appropriate. For the output I would need to get a Seq of ints that contain sum of last 2 days of data, for example:

```
Seq(10, 30, 30, 17) # 2019-01-01 has only 1 day with sum value of 10 since there is no data for 2018-12-31, 2019-01-02 would be 30 since we have 2nd and 1st of Jan present, etc...
```

This is not overly difficult to do in base python, however with Scala there seem to be quite a few options (recursive use of folds?) but I am struggling with the syntax and implementation. Would anyone be able to shed some light on this?

Comment: First a few advices. Do not use **Seq**, it is a failed abstraction, see [this](https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/2ae2570c8856037a7738) for a detailed explanation. I would suggest you to use always **List** or **Set** or **Map**. Also, do not use **JodaTime** that has been deprecated for a while. Use the `java.time` package from **Java 8**.

Comment: I am not on my computer but I can give a few quick suggestions from what I think you are asking. If this wasn't a rolling sum, the way to go about this would be groupBy day, and then sum/fold and then you can filter this Map for the last 2 days, if it is not present it will just return one day. So let's get to the rolling part. To be honest I don't think seq is the right structure for that. I believe stream fits a little bit better

Comment: Now for your question, since you are learning I would suggest you to write a _tail-recursive_ algorithm and then rewrite that using `foldLeft`. - But here is a simple one liner that works on **Scala 2.13** `data.groupMapReduce(_. date.atStartOfDay)(_.volume)(_ + _)`

Comment: If you are on an older version of Scala, you can do this `data.groupBy(_.date.atStartOfDay).view.mapValues(_.map(_.volume).reduce(_ + _)).toMap`

Comment: "Not all dates may be present ..."  Did you mean the rolling sums only apply to consecutive dates?  If so, you might want to expand your sample data to cover cases of non-consecutive dates and the expected output.

Comment: You can paste your works python code(without using of pandas or numpy) here.

Answer (score 1):

You say "not all dates may be present" but you don't specify how date gaps should be handled.

Here I guessed that output should include all 2-day sums, gap days included.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS

case class SymbolData(date     : LocalDate
                     ,open     : Double
                     ,high     : Double
                     ,low      : Double
                     ,close    : Double
                     ,adjClose : Double
                     ,volume   : Int)

val sampleData: List[SymbolData] = List(
  SymbolData(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-01"), 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10),
  SymbolData(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-02"), 3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 8.0, 20),
  SymbolData(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-03"), 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10),
  SymbolData(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-04"), 4.0, 3.0, 2.5, 2.3, 5.3, 7),
  // 1 day gap
  SymbolData(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-06"), 4.4, 3.3, 2.2, 2.3, 1.3, 13),
  // 2 day gap
  SymbolData(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-09"), 2.4, 2.2, 1.5, 3.1, 0.9, 21),
  SymbolData(LocalDate.parse("2019-01-10"), 2.4, 2.2, 1.5, 3.1, 0.9, 11)
)

val volByDate = sampleData.foldLeft(Map.empty[LocalDate,Int]){
  case (m,sd) => m + (sd.date -> sd.volume)
}.withDefaultValue(0)

val startDate = sampleData.head.date
val endDate   = sampleData.last.date

val rslt = List.unfold(startDate){ date =>  //<--Scala 2.13
  if (date isAfter endDate) None
  else
    Some(volByDate(date) + volByDate(date.minus(1L,DAYS)) -> date.plus(1L,DAYS))
}
//rslt: List[Int] = List(10, 30, 30, 17, 7, 13, 13, 0, 21, 32)
```